# you must supply CFbundleidentifier for this request

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, cfbundleidentifier

I have been trying to upload my build (Xcode 8.1) since almost a week and i get n number of errors,which i do not get on my any other app update.This is not my first upload. I am just trying to update the app. I get the error of you must supply CFBundleIdentifier for this request.

Comment: Have you checked you info.plist file if CFBundleIdentifier exists or not?

Comment: @Poles Yes i checked it does exist. I have also used GooglePlus framework which has its own plist and that too has CFBundleIdentifier

Comment: Try to upload the using *Application Loader*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally figure out the error. It was that all my provisioning profiles went invalid when i checked it in my developer account.I had to recreate it and then everything went good with the upload.